# Redux:TypeError: Cannot read property 'modal' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

i just started to write code in redux and am facing some issues while getting value from redux store

browse-upload.js

```
const initialState = {
    modal: false
};

const browseUploadReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_MODAL_INFORMATION: {
            return {
                ...state,
                modal: true
            };
        }
        case GET_CLOSE_MODAL_INFORMATION: {
            return {
                ...state,
                modal: false
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
            break;
    }
};

export const getModalOpen = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: GET_MODAL_INFORMATION
    });
};

export const getModalClose = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: GET_CLOSE_MODAL_INFORMATION
    });
};

export default browseUploadReducer;
```

and in my component , i just tried to retrieve the value from store

```
import { getModalOpen,getModalClose} from 'reducers/star/browse-upload';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    modal: state.modal,
});
```

what might went wrong ?Still control not coming back to component? How can i verify that?

Comment: Can you share your root reducer file?

Comment: have you added `browseUploadReducer` to your `combineReducer` function.

Comment: Can you share the complete error stack trace? Thanks

Comment: Can you try this:

`const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    modal: state.modal
});`

Comment: if you console your `state.browseUpload` its `undefined`. therefore, you are getting `undefine.modal` where as undefined is not an object. so, first you should get an object or a value in `state.browseUpload`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `mapStateToProps`, write this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ modal: state.modal });
```

I think issue is; there is no such thing called `browseUpload` *defined* in your state that is why you are getting the error.

Comment: , am not getting back modal value
const browseUploadReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_ASSETS_LIST: {
            return {
                ...state,
                modal:true,
                currentSection:action.payload
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

Comment: @muhammad Zeeshan i can see control in my reducer ,but i guess its not coming back to my component, also am not getting value in const mapStateToProps = state => ({ modal: state.modal });

based on this am taking modal value in render and trying to console,its not showing

Comment: Can you share the code where you are trying to get the value of modal and also update the complete reducer file code?